# Link to user profile in stackexchange.com Hot Questions list is broken when the account is deleted

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, deleted-accounts

On the [hot questions list](//stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), there's a question ([this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342819/execute-as-test-rather-than-test)) which has been asked by a deleted user:

> [image]

On the hot-questions page, the user is clickable. But leads to a dead link:

> [image]

It is [this url](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users//user214467).

Not a major bug, but I thought I'd mention it. A quick search didn't find it already posted.

Comment: Well no wonder it wasn't yet reported, it's very rare. Usually when a user gets so many upvotes and answer  they won't go and delete their account. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's what I was thinking too. you don't get many deleted accounts on the hot list. I think this was because the asker ended up in a edit war on the question (see the question edit history) so I don't know if the deletion what their own choice or an act of moderation.

Comment: Huh, so weird... wonder how such a thing ended up as hot question. Well, usually moderator will just suspend such a user for a day to cool off, so most likely the user asked to delete their account.